# TypeError when calling an unbound method, but class _does_ define that method

Tags: python, methods

I am getting an error when calling a method, but the object upon which the method is being called does define that method.

Here is where the method is called:

```
def interpreter(self, ast, expression, stack) # method in Parser.py file
    ...
    elif isinstance(ast, ReadNode):
            self.interpret(ast.location, environment, stack)
            loc = stack.pop()
            input = sys.stdin.read()
            try:
                num = int(input)
            except:
                sys.stderr.write("error: not an integer")
            loc.set(num)
    ...
```

I am getting an error on `loc.set(num)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/filepath/Parser.py", line 846, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/filepath/Parser.py", line 844, in main
    p.parse()
  File "/home/filepath/Parser.py", line 75, in parse
    self.interpret(instructions, environment, stack)
  File "/home/filepath/Parser.py", line 128, in interpret
    loc.set(num)
TypeError: unbound method set() must be called with IntegerBox instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Here is the IntegerBox class:

```
from Box import Box

class IntegerBox(Box):

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

When I go through the debugger to check the type of `loc`, it is an `IntegerBox` instance. Why does it think that `loc` is not an IntegerBox instance then?

Comment: You need to show the code of `interpret`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loc is not an instance of IntegerBox, it is the IntegerBox class.

For example:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def m(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> C.m()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method m() must be called with C instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

but:

```
>>> c = C()    # create an instance
>>> c.m()  # no error
>>>
```

You need to check what is being put into the stack object.

Edit: explain unbound methods

When a method is called on an instance, the instance is implicitly passed as the first parameter - this is the `self` parameter in the method signature.  If the method is called on the Class rather than an instance, an instance must be explicitly passed otherwise a `TypeError` for an unbound method will be raised because the method is not "bound" to a specific instance of the class.

So:
`C.m()` raises a `TypeError`

`C().m()` is ok

`C.m(C())` is also ok!

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you know that the class was being called instead of the object?

Comment: @JeremyFisher because tht's what an unbound method signifies - I've added more to the answer.

Comment: Also, we can tell this is Python 2, because Python 3 did away with unbound methods as a separate type...  They never found any use for the distinction, so "unbound methods" are just normal functions in Python 3.  You can still make the same mistake --- using the class name instead of an instance name --- but the error message would be "TypeError: m() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)", same as any other function.